Ubuntu: How to remove old software center after upgrade to 24.04
I just upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04 and there are a couple of old softwares still around and I want to get rid of them.
Check the screenshot - I have 2 Software centers and 2 Software Updates
They each open separate windows - the new and old ones.
How can I remove the old ones?


This question is similar to: Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The first Software icon refers to software in GNOME project software which can be useful if you want to install non-snap software. I would advice you keep this one as it will be handy if you ever want to get rid of snap and get back to good old days deb packages. The next two are useful tools for updating  and selecting the type of upgrades and you must not remove them. The last one is Ubuntu software store so it is reasonably useful.

The gray one (#2) is the software that will search and propose updates to your Ubuntu system. The blue one (#3) is the Settings of the #2 application.
